# Basic Conventional routing asp.net webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a simple query on ASP.Net Web API Routing. I have the following controller:

```
public class CustomersController: ApiController
{
    public List<SomeClass> Get(string searchTerm)
    {
         if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
         {
             //return complete List
         }
         else
         {
             //return list.where (Customer name contains searchTerm)
         }
    }
}
```

My routing configuration (Conventional) looks like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:"DefaultApi",
routeTemplate:"api/{controller}/{id}"
defaults:new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:"CustomersApi",
routeTemplate:"api/{controller}/{searchTerm}"
defaults:new {searchTerm = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

If I hit the url:
http://localhost:57169/api/Customers/Vi 
I get a 404-Not found

If I reverse the order of the routes, it works.
So the question is in the first case, is it matching the first route (DefaultApi)? If not, why is it not trying the second route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This route template

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:"DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate:"api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults:new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
);
```

match your URL because `Id` can be any type : `string`, `int` etc. So your URL respect this template and this route is chosen.

To make this template more restrcitive and make ASP.Net Web API to go to the next template you need to add to it some constraints by saying something like "*`Id` parameter must be a numeric type for this template*". So you add `constraints` parameter like below:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:"DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Required}, // <- also here I put Required to make sure that when your user doesn't give searchTerm so this template will not be chosen.
    constraints: new {id = @"\d+"} // <- regular expression is used to say that id must be numeric value for this template.
);
```

So by using this URL **http://localhost:57169/api/Customers/Vi** the above template will be skipped and the next will be chosen.

Comment: If this route is chosen, then why does it not trigger the Controller method? Is it because the parameter name in the Controller method is searchTerm and not id?

Comment: It chosen but there is no action in Customers controller that take "id" as a parameter. When action is not found it return 404. ASP.Net Web API will not return again into your template litst to take another route template.

Comment: So what you are saying is, the route resolution does not take the parameter name into account. First the route is chosen and then the parameters are matched. Is that correct?